# Sbt generated docker container fails to package subproject

Tags: scala, docker, sbt, sbt-native-packager, finch

I have a multi-project build.sbt file, with projects like so:

```
lazy val utils = (project in file("utils"))
  .settings(
    Seq(
      publishArtifact := false
    )).[...]


lazy val api = (project in file("api"))
  .dependsOn(utils)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .enablePlugins(JavaAppPackaging, DockerPlugin)
  .settings(publish := {})
  .settings(
    Seq(
      packageName in Docker := "my-api",
      dockerBaseImage := "java:8",
      mainClass in Compile := Some("com.path.to.Main"),
      publishArtifact := false,
      unmanagedJars in Compile += file("jars/somejars.jar")
    ))
```

API is built on top of Finch framework. I create a docker image for the API using `sbt api/docker:publishLocal` and then run it locally. However, it seems like the `utils` subproject classes are not packaged with the final container, and as a result I am getting multiple

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
```

types of exceptions. For a similar project that doesn't have a subproject dependency, everything runs smoothly and I have no problems.

Am I missing something in the plugin configuration? I thought `.dependsOn()` should be taking care of providing dependent classes in the project docker image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question, but turns out this is a default behaviour of `sbt-native-packager`, or rather `sbt`, when a dependent project has `publishArtifact := false` setting.

A workaround that worked for me was changing the above to `publish/skip := true`.

More on this issue can be found here: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/issues/1221